# Defining a generic method

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I was wondering if I could create a method outside a class in Python.
For example, in this supposed method I wanted to create references to an integer number, and check whether or not it is prime.

The code I'd like to create would be something like this:

```
def is_prime(self):

    for x in range(1, self):
        if self % x == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

`self` is the integer number to which the method is applied.
So a theoretical use of this would be:

```
random_integer: int = 53

if random_integer.is_prime():
    print(f"{random_integer} is a prime number.")
else:
    print(f"{random_integer} is not prime.")
```

A way I tried to implement this was by writing this code:

```
class Number(float):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.__num = num

    def is_prime(self):
        root = round(self.__num**0.5)
        for x in range(2, root):
            if self.__num % x == 0 and x < root:
                return False
        return True


var = Number(54)
print(var.is_prime())  # --> returns False
```

Is it possible to create generic methods (or methods that only apply to certain types - e.g. int, float, str) in Python?
Or are we 'stuck' with functions that only take them as parameters and don't use `self`?

I'm a beginner programmer, so please be clear with your answers :) and thanks in advance!

Comment: It kind of does. I'll look more into it later and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Note that what you are looking for is commonly called an *extension method*.